# HTML progress element not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a problem I've been struggling with for a while now.  I've implemented an HTML5 `progress` element like so:

```
      <progress id="progress" value="0" max="100"></progress><output class="percent" id="percent">0</output><span class="prozent">%</span>
```

Suppose I update the value of `progress` and `percent` in a JS loop:

```
  i = 0;
  pBar = document.getElementById('progress');
  pBar.value = i;//start at 0%
  percent = 1;//set target for next progress bar update in %
  //DO
  do {
    //IF(i > i_max) EXIT
    //CALL VERLET
    VERLET(i, x, v, a, time, const0, gamma, A_o, omega, dt);
    x_plot[i] = [time[i], x[i]];
    v_plot[i] = [time[i], v[i]];
    a_plot[i] = [time[i], a[i]];
    //i = i + 1
    i = i + 1;
    if (parseInt(i / i_max * 100, 10) === percent) {
      pBar.value = percent;//update progress bar
      document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = percent;
      percent = percent + 1;
    }
  //END DO
  } while (i < i_max);
```

This is the relevant portion of my script.  **Please assume all variables are properly declared and initialized, and the script as whole is linted.**  A draft of the page can be found [here](http://pages.suddenlink.net/physics/driven/driven.htm).

I don't understand why the values of the `progress` and `output` elements are not updated until after the calculation is finished.  Or this is what appears to happen.  IE11(?) seems to show some updating when initially loading the page, but again doesn't update the progress bar for a new calculation without reloading.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743428/javascript-progress-bar-not-updating-on-the-fly-but-all-at-once-once-process) is something along similar lines, but not using this modern method.  I've taken a stab at getting [this](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/) example to work, without success.  [This](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/07/displaying-the-progress-of-tasks-with-html5/) example, though better written I think, might shed some light on the problem.

Is it a timeout issue?  Is there a simple jQuery method I could make use of?  Any feedback on this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't update the DOM in a while loop.

Comment: `Do...While` are synchronous. The browser *stop* while doing it. Use something asynchronous like a timer instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I got my progress bar to animate:

**HTML**

```
<progress id="progress" value="0" max="100"></progress><output class="percent" id="percent">0</output><span class="prozent">%</span>
```

**JS**

```
start = new Date().getTime();
//do stuff
end = new Date().getTime();
t = (end - start);
document.getElementById('progress').value = 0;
document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = 0;
if (parseInt(t / 100.0, 10) <= 1) {
  t = 1;//minimum update interval in ms
} else {
  t = parseInt(t / 100.0, 10);//actual update interval in ms
}
go = setInterval(animate, t);
value = 0;
max = 100;
go = 0;
function animate() {
  if (value >= max) {
    clearInterval(go);
    return;
  }
  value += 1;
  document.getElementById('progress').value = value;
  document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = value;
  if (value === max) {
    clearInterval(go);
  }
}
```

This script can be invoked when the page loads via `<body onload="amp()">` or when prompted by the user with `<input type="number" name="theta0" id="theta0" value="0.1" min="0.0" max="1.6" step="0.1" onchange="amp()">`.  As you can see, the update interval is tied to the CPU clock time in ms since I can't update the DOM while in a `while` loop.  It's clunky, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do those kind of operations in a single while-loop.

What happens is the loop will run until it ends and you'll only be able to *see* the result when it finishes the operation.

For this kind of problems you should go for an asynchronous way.

```
function updateDom() {
  // do stuff

  setTimeout(updateDom, 500);
}

setTimeout(updateDom, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

As [@epascarello says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821961/html-progress-element-not-updating/27822041#comment44049591_27821961), you cant update the DOM in a `while` loop.
Update it with an interval:

```
var interval = setInterval(function () {
  VERLET(i, x, v, a, time, const0, gamma, A_o, omega, dt);
  x_plot[i] = [time[i], x[i]];
  v_plot[i] = [time[i], v[i]];
  a_plot[i] = [time[i], a[i]];
  i = i + 1;
  if (parseInt(i / i_max * 100, 10) === percent) {
    pBar.value = percent;//update progress bar
    document.getElementById('percent').innerHTML = percent;
    percent = percent + 1;
  }
  if (i < i_max) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Intervals are evil. Even if the operation doesn't finish, it will execute the function again, which could show the progress bar going backwards in some cases.