# Update CSS before Javascript (jQuery) is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been reading about the single-thread nature of javascript and how the UI will not update until the code is complete (eg. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743428/javascript-progress-bar-not-updating-on-the-fly-but-all-at-once-once-process)).  The responses to that question mainly explained how the code executes, but didn't provide a real viable solution outside of some "hacky" timers.

I'm wondering if there is a good solution, that may include promises, or `.then()` functionality that will "paint" the UI prior to javascript execution.

The following is a specific example: http://jsfiddle.net/zbtsd12k/.  In this example I would expect the "Change Color" to change immediately, prior to the calculation being run.

**WARNING**: My example includes a for-loop of one billion iterations (which took < 2 seconds on my machine) and may freeze your computer for a bit.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is it just me who finds this question unclear?

Comment: @treyBake - did you try the example?  It should be pretty obvious what I'm asking.

Comment: I did .... it just didn't make sense | edit: wait are you asking, change colour should run before the calculations even start?

Comment: @treyBake - yes.  Color should change immediately, then the calculations run.  Which is what I wrote in my original question.

Comment: Why not do an AJAX (**asynchronous** JavaScript and XML) request then? o.O

Comment: You can allow the dom the chance to update by putting your logic in a setTimeout with a low timeout threshold

Comment: @treyBake - I'm not familiar with AJAX requests that aren't meant for GET or POST functions.  If you want to update my JSFiddle and post an answer, I'll accept it if it gets the job done.

Comment: @Taplar - great idea, and very succinct.

Comment: @elPastor it can be and I think the primary use is for updates without refresh. However, it may be utilised to be used for things like this - I could be wrong, I'm no AJAX/JS expert, but AJAX was the first thing that came to mind after realising the question

Comment: @elPastor https://jsfiddle.net/zbtsd12k/3/ <-- it errors in console, but if you make a normal page and open in browser it works

Comment: I don't understand the creation of an ajax request, *just* to detach the logic from the main thread execution.  That's major overkill

Comment: @treyBake - that's it.  I'm surprised the `url` param needs to be there, but I tried it without and it fails.  Thank you!

Comment: @elPastor I don't know if it does (you can experiment) but glad it helps :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few changes

- Added a `setTimeout` around the "logic" so that the DOM has a chance to redraw
- Broke apart the `then(makeCalculations())` line because #1 `updateClass()` does not return a promise and #2 `then(methodCall())` would execute the methodCall immediately because you put `()` on the end of it.

```js
function updateClass(element, newClass) {
  element.addClass(newClass);
  return true;
};

function makeCalculations() {
  $("p").text("Running...");

  setTimeout(function() {
    var x = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
      x += i;
    }

    $("p").html("Done!" + "<br />" + "x = " + x);
  }, 10);
}

$(function() {

  $("button").click(function() {

    updateClass($("span"), "purple");
    makeCalculations();

  });

});
```

```css
.purple {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Change Color</span>
<br>
<button>Click Me</button>
<p>Click the button</p>
```

Comment: thanks for putting this together, it is much appreciated.